# NetBeans magic-method signatures and autocomplete; changing default parameter names

Tags: php, netbeans, parameters, autocomplete, method-signature

Quick one:

I'm still a NetBeans amateur, however I've grown very fond of it very quickly. Anyways, running 7.0 for PHP development, and I'm wondering if its possible to change the method signatures of PHP's magic-methods.

For instance, as a convention I (*almost*) always use `$key` as the parameter for `__get()`, as opposed to the auto-generated `$name`.

So after <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +   <kbd>Space</kbd>   and selecting the method `__get()` it produces:

```
public function __get($name){
    ;
}
```

How can I change `$name` to `$key`? I'm guessing it's pulling from a core PHPDoc or something, so there may be not way to change this, but if there is, I'd love to know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is hard coded. It's basically not possible to customize it. But you can fire an enhancement to the Bugzilla.

Comment: Thanks **Petr**; I figured as much. I believe I will send a feature request.